Getting Error in flutter What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. >
i am using the flutter_multi_image_picker this dependency i am getting error of    > Could not find com.sangcomz:FishBun:0.11.2. this is old dependency is this expire or something else if this is expire which dependency i can use please . solve this
i am just try to select multiple image i was expecting it should work .
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.    > Could not find com.sangcomz:FishBun:0.11.2.      Searched in the following locations:        - https://dl.google.com/dl

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You are asking question specifically related to package flutter_multi_image_picker. After going to package link on pub dev, I found last development was done on this package 23 months ago. This package is no longer maintained. You can achieve multi selection of images using image_picker
final List<XFile> images = await picker.pickMultiImage();

